# In Python, strange use of *args and **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x

In some project, there is this line of code:

```
curry(nn_task, latplan.model.get(parameters["aeclass"]), path, train, train, val, val, parameters)
```

Where:

```
def curry(fn,*args1,**kwargs1):
    return lambda *args,**kwargs: fn(*args1,*args,**{**kwargs1,**kwargs})
```

and:

```
def nn_task(network, path, train_in, train_out, val_in, val_out, parameters, resume=False):
    ....
```

But when I call *curry* with an extra parameter ("resume"):

```
curry(nn_task, latplan.model.get(parameters["aeclass"]), path, train, train, val, val, parameters, resume=True)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: nn_task() got multiple values for argument 'resume'

Any idea ?

Thanks

*p.s:* I cannot modify the code (I want to use it as it is)

[EDIT]:
I also tried this:

```
curry(nn_task, latplan.model.get(parameters["aeclass"]), path, train, train, val, val, parameters, True)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: nn_task() takes from 7 to 8 positional arguments but 9 were
> given

Comment: Is `curry` a function you have to use because it does more than is stated here, or does it literally only do what you've posted?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, `curry` returns a function with the expected signature `<function __main__.curry.<locals>.<lambda>(*args, **kwargs)>`

Comment: @blueteeth indeed, after having looked, I think curry is only used in this case, so I might modify it ?

Comment: @blueteeth if it's the case, well I don't know how to modify it

Comment: What do you expect or want the output to be?